# How to group by more than 64 keys in BigQuery

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

Using Google-BigQuery, I created a query with almost 100 fields, grouping by 96 of them:

```
SELECT 
    field1,field2,(...),MAX(field100) as max100
FROM dataset.table1
GROUP BY field1,field2,(...),field96
```

and I got this error

```
Error: Maximum number of keys in GROUP BY clause is 64, query has 96 GROUP BY keys.
```

so, there is no chance to group by more than 64 fields using google-bigquery. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If some of these fields are strings, and there is a character which cannot appear in them (say, ':'), then you could concatenate them together and group by concatenation, i.e.

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, ':', field2, ':', field3) as composite_field, ...
FROM dataset.table
GROUP BY 1, 2, ..., 64
```

In order to recover the original fields later, you could use

```
SELECT 
regexp_extract(composite_field, r'([^:]*):') field1,
regexp_extract(composite_field, r'[^:]*:([^:]*)') field2, 
regexp_extract(composite_field, r'[^:]*:[^:]*:(.*)') field3,
...
FROM (...)
```

Comment: That is a solution, but if I need it as derived query, I need better ways.

Comment: I expanded solution to show how to recover the original fields after GROUP BY is done.

Comment: I guess since group key maps uniquely to field1, ... - you can take any value of field1 in a group, e.g. MAX(field1) instead of recovering it later.

SELECT CONCAT(field1, ':', field2, ':', ....) as composite_key,
  MAX(field1) as field1, MAX(field2) as field2, ...
FROM table
GROUP BY composite_key

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is an internal limit, not documented.

Another solution that I have developed is similar to the Mosha's solution.

You can add an extra column called, for example, `hashref`. That new column is computed by all the columns that you would like to group by, separated with a pipe for example and applying `md5` or `sha256` to the line.

Then you can group by with the new `hashref` and for the other columns you just apply the `min()` function, that is also an aggregator.

```
line = name + "|" + surname + "|" + age
hashref = md5(line)
```

... and then ...

```
SELECT hashref, min(name), min(surname)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY hashref
```

Comment: In the select : bidref? hashref? I get the idea, but this looks not quite right.

Comment: You are right Clay, sorry for the mix. I mixed the example names and the names that I use it in my own solution.